# HttpListener behind a router

Tags: c#, dns, httplistener

I have just finished a program what can used to save webpages (I need it for specific reasons) and I wrote a html frontend to use it (a form), and it works, BUT only if I browse the page from localhost [localhost:4001], if I try to use my dynamic dns address, my HttpListener can't receive a request (it's port forwarded, and uTorrent webui works, with it's connection port)

I dont want to post my full code it's just a lot of string processing, but some parts:

```
server = new HttpListener();
server.Prefixes.Add("http://+:4001/");
public void StartListening()
{
   server.Start();
   server.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ContextProc), null);
}
```

Have I left something, what is needed for HttpListener to receive connection through the internet?

(I've tried to use port 80 [usually apache uses this port], nothing happened)

Comment: Have you tried to browse to the internal address of you box (ex. 192.168.1.1:4001) both from the box itself (to verify that the application is listening on the interface and not only loopback) and also from another box internal to your network?  If so and no workie; then you can narrow it down to your router but you would need to provide information about your router.

Comment: It works with my private ip address, I dont think it's the routers problem, everything else works (apache,utorrent), and I used dyndns-s open port tool, and it indicates that the port (4001) isn't opened. I think this could be the problem, but how could I open that port?

Comment: OK i'm stupid, I played with portforwarding for days, and I accidentally removed the forwarding from 4001, and _then_ I noticed that the firewall is _on_, now the problem solved.